# What is bios in "Social media bios"?

Tags: word-usage

Social media services also enabled people to publicize their views on new songs, list their new favorite bands in their social media **bios**.

My research is this: bio: Bio- is used at the beginning of nouns and adjectives that refer to life or to the study of living things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is short for *biographies* or *biographical profiles*.